# Concern about ratio of triangle lengths with a cevian.

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Let the base $AB$ of a triangle $\triangle ABC$ be fixed and the vertex $C$ lie on a fixed circle of radius $r$ . Lines are drawn through $A$ and $B$ to intersect $BC$ and $CA$ at $E$ and $F$ respectively such that $CE:EB=1:2$ and $CF:FA=1:2$. If the point of intersection of these line is called $P$ and lies on the median through $C$ for all positions of $C$, then the locus of $P$ is :
>
> $ (1)$ Circle of radius $\dfrac r2$ 
> $(2)$ Circle of radius $2r$ 
>  $(3)$a parabola of latus rectum $4r$ 
> $(4)$ a rectangular hyperbola

[image]

#### My thoughts:

- The last statement about $P$ lying on the median always, seems to be superfluous, as $CP$ *must* be a part of the median in order to satisfy Ceva’s theorem.
- By the converse of the Basic Proportionality Theorem/Thales’ Theorem, $FE\parallel AB$.
- Note that the circle in question is completely arbitrary  and **not** the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$.

#### Questionable solution on the internet:

Let $D$ be the origin and let $C(\alpha,\beta)$. Now, $$\color{red}{\dfrac{CP}{PD}\overset{\color{blue}{????}}{=}\frac{CF}{FA}+\frac{CE}{EB}}=\frac12+\frac12=1$$ so $P$ is the midpoint of $CD$. Thus, $P\equiv \left(\dfrac{\alpha}{2},\dfrac{\beta}{2}\right)$ and if $C$ lies on $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ then $P$ lies on $x^2+y^2+2\frac g2x+2\frac f2y+\frac c4=0$ whose radius is $\dfrac r2$.

#### Finally:

1. Why is the $\color{red}{\text{highlighted}}$ statement in the solution true? I can see $P$ is the midpoint by mass-point geometry, but not the general case.
2. Is there a pure geometrical way to look at it instead of this (admittedly short and sweet) coordinate method?

Comment: This is working backward. If we know that $CP=PD$, we can show that the locus is a circle as follows: Let the center of Circle$ABC$ be $O$ and $M$ be the mid-point of $OD$. By mid-point theorem, $MP=\frac{OC}{2}=\frac{r}{2}$. Hence the locus is a circle with radius $\frac {r}{2}$, centred at $M$.

Comment: To prove that $CP=PD$, we can extend $PD$ to $Q$ such that $PD=DQ$ and join $BQ$ and $AQ$. Notice that $APBQ$ is a parallelogram. $\Delta CPE \sim \Delta CQB $ because $AP // QB$. This implies that $CP:PQ=1:2$ and hence $CP:PD=1:1$

Comment: Love the effort put into presentation. Where did this question come from? It seems really really difficult!

Comment: @ BeautifullyIrrational Ah, this was provided in a preparatory exam. I am actually more interested in finding the truth behind the general, red equality, rather than specifically CP:PD=1:1, which @LiKwokKeung so nicely demonstrated with the beautiful construction.

Comment: You can write a self answer expanding on their comment  if it solved your question .@insipidintegrator

Comment: No, actually it didn’t. It works on only a specific case, while I am asking the general, red case.

Comment: @insipidintegrator, Thanks for adding the figure for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $S$ be the mid-point of $BE$. Join $DS$. Then by mid-point theorem, $ES=SB$. Hence
$$\frac{CE}{ES}=\frac{CE}{\frac{EB}{2}}=2×\frac{CE}{EB}$$

But $\Delta CPE\sim \Delta CDS$ implies that
$$\frac{CP}{PD}=\frac{CE}{ES}=2\times\frac{CE}{EB}$$
Similarly by joining the mid-point $T$ of $AF$ and $D$, we can prove that
$$\frac{CP}{PD}=2\times\frac{CF}{FA}$$
Combining both equations, we get
$$\frac{CP}{PD}=\frac{CE}{EB}+\frac{CF}{FA}$$

---

More generally, if $CE:EB=\alpha:1$ and $CF:FA=\beta: 1$.

By Ceva's Theorem, we can prove that $AD:DB=\alpha: \beta$.

Draw $DS$ parallel to $AE$, meeting $BC$ at $S$.

Then $\Delta BDS \sim \Delta BAE$ implies that $$ES:EB=\alpha:\alpha+\beta=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}:1$$

Together with $$CE:EB=\alpha:1$$
we have
$$CE:ES=\alpha:\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}=\alpha+\beta:1$$

Note also that $AE//DS$ implies that $CP:PD=CE:ES$

Hence
$$CP:PD=CE:ES=\alpha+\beta:1=\frac{CE}{EB}+\frac{CF}{FA}$$

Comment: Sorry, I am a new comer. I do not know how to copy the figure. Can you add it for me?